# moving rows into different sections

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, tableview

Hey guys I have two sections on my tableview and I have a mutable array that updates only one section. I would like to move the cells from the section with an array into the blank section. I tried creating another array for the blank section itself but I wasn't able to get it working. Here is my moveRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{

id objectToMove = [myArray1 objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
id objectToMove2 = [myArray2 objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

//move objects between main section
[myArray1 removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[myArray1 insertObject:objectToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];


//move object from main section to blank section
 [myArray1 removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
 [myArray2 insertObject:objectToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
```

I have my numberOfRowsInSection returning the appropriate arrays count for each section but still no luck. When I enter editing mode and I try to move the cell it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this code.

```
NSString * cell = nil;
switch (fromIndexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell = [[myArray2 objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
        [myArray2 removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell = [[myArray1 objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
        [myArray1 removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
        break;
    }

switch (destinationIndexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        [myArray2 insertObject:cell atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        [myArray1 insertObject:cell atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        break;

}

[cell release];
```